# UDP connection between Lua server and Java client

Tags: java, sockets, lua

I'm working with a **UDP** **Client** (written in **Java**) and a **Server** (written in **Lua**). I'm using Lua Socket for the server and DatagramSockets for the client. Connection gets established successfully. The problem is when Lua server sends a string to the Java client, Java **receive()** function does not get the data and blocks. pls help me.

Lua server code:

```
-- Server

local socket = require("socket")

host = host or "*"
port = port or 8080

s = assert(socket.bind(host, port))
c = assert(s:accept())


data = "hello"

while true
do
        assert(c:send(data .. "\n"))
        socket.sleep(1)
--      return 0;
end
```

Java client code :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Clientnew
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                DatagramSocket ds = null;
                byte[] Message = new byte[100];

                try {
                        InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                        Socket client = new Socket(IP, 8080);

                        ds = new DatagramSocket(8080);
                        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(Message, 1);
                        ds.receive(dp);

                        System.out.println("Recv\n");
                        String str = new String(dp.getData());

                        System.out.println(str);

                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                } finally
                {
                        if (ds != null)
                        {
                                ds.close();
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

Both program run on the Linux Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Lua code is a TCP Server, not a UDP one. Also, remember that UDP is connectionless...

http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html

You can use standard tools like `netstat` to check things like this.